# 2 address on 1 server dont ping

Tags: networking, ubuntu-16.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrmpi.png)
ifconfig

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD7LP.png)
interface

I have a problem, I would like to add 2 addresses to my server, but when I add it to interfaces, it shows up in ifconfig but does not ping me

Comment: That IP address is in a completely different subnet. Is that subnet routed properly to your server?

Comment: And please, don't post screenshots of text that can be copied. Just copy&paste it.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: netmask of the eth0:0 interface is wrong.

There should be other problems like asymmetric routing it is depends your infrastructure configuration.

I personmally don't like to add more than one interface to a server because it should produce problems like i.e. security, routing. There are 2 exception for me:

1. The server act as a network device, i.e. router, gateway or firewall.
2. There is an OOB (out-of-band) management network in the infrastructure.